# jQuery "Uncaught URIError: URI malformed" Error with Emoticons

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm using the following JavaScript code that works with pretty much everything but emotions. I keep receiving the following error.

> Uncaught URIError: URI malformed

If I change the value of `a_msg` from `""` to something else, it works! Note that in practice I'm collecting these values from a `textarea`, so I don't really have control over the encoding of the characters entered there, as it is often dependent on the (virtual) keyboards used.

```
var a_name = "my name";
var a_msg = "";
$.post("myphp.php", { name: a_name, msg: a_msg });
```

My PHP code is also straightforward.

```
$name = $_POST["name"];
$msg = $_POST["msg"];
```

The Webpage uses UTF-8 charset.

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

So far I have tried (based on similar questions posted on the forum),

1. `encodeURIt()`, ``` encodeURIComponent()``decodeURIComponent() ``` and `decodeURI()`in the JavaScript,
2. `escape()` works if the original text does not contain "%",
3. `utf8_encode()` in the PHP, and
4. `<form accept-charset="ISO-8859-1">` in the HTML.

But no luck or whatsoever.

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I see two solutions to this: (1) force the entry of UTF-8 encoded text on the textarea, (2) convert UTF-16 (or other encoding) to UTF-8 the moment users inputs it. But I can't figure out how to do either of these.

Answer (score 0):

May it helps you. I have try to reproduce the issue. This is my solution:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Titel der Seite</title>
    <script src="jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <script>
    var a_name = "my name";
    var a_msg = "";
    $.post("myphp.php", { name: a_name, msg: a_msg});
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

myphp.php:

```
<?php

$name = $_POST["name"];
$msg = iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-8', $_POST["msg"]);

echo $msg;
?>
```

As default my files are encoded in UTF-8(Notepad++ under Encoding -> Encode in UTF-8).

Comment: Thanks for the response! Yet this doesn't work for me. I think the reason is, in your files the default encoding is UTF-8. What I think happens in my case is, when the user changes the keyboard layout to enter emoticons, the encoding changes from UTF-8 to UTF-16. Let's assume the user is entering "I am happy  today". In this case, the encoding changes the moment the user enters the emoticon. So the system handles "I am happy " just fine, but throws error for " today".